# Getting unauthorized 401 error on using github token

Tags: reactjs, github, react-redux, axios, github-api

Hi I created a new personalized token for github and am using that in my .env.local file. It should grant access to the app to fetch users from github. But it is showing a 401 error in the console. It was working fine just a day ago. I also created a new token for this but the error is the same.

Here is the code that I am using in react:

```
const github = axios.create({
baseURL: "https://api.github.com",
timeout: 1000,
headers: { Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN },
});

class App extends Component {
state = {
users: [],
loading: false,
alert: null,
};

static propTypes = {
searchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


searchUsers = async (text) => {
this.setState({ loading: true });

const res = await github.get(`/search/users?q=${text}`);

this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
};

//Clear users from state

clearUsers = () => this.setState({ users: [], loading: false });

//Set Alert
setAlert = (msg, type) => {
this.setState({ alert: { msg, type } });

setTimeout(() => this.setState({ alert: null }), 5000);
};

render() {
const { users, loading } = this.state;
return (

    <div className="conatiner">
      <Alert alert={this.state.alert} />
      <Search
        searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
        clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
        showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
        setAlert={this.setAlert}
      />
      <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

why is this error being shown?
```

My github token is like this in .env.local

REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN='token '

Comment: Strange, I just used `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=brad` on my navigator without any token and got a json list as expected. Why did you use the token here, is it related to axios?